# RxJava2 throttleFirst()

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a `Flowable`, that in `create()` I am doing the following:

```
it.onNext(0)
Thread.sleep(500) // 500ms
it.onNext(500)
Thread.sleep(600) // 1100ms
it.onNext(1100)
Thread.sleep(600) // 1700ms
it.onNext(1700)
Thread.sleep(1200) // 2900ms
it.onNext(2900)
Thread.sleep(200) // 3100ms
it.onNext(3100)
Thread.sleep(200) // 3300ms
it.onNext(3300)
Thread.sleep(800) // 4100ms
it.onNext(4100)
```

Then I am using the `throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to receive the first emitted item for every 1 second passed.

For time passed I think that I should get:

- 0 for [0s - 1s)
- 1100 for [1s - 2s)
- 2900 for [2s - 3s)
- **3100 for [3s - 4s)**
- 4100 for [4s - end)

But, I receive all the above apart from **3100** value? What could be wrong and I don't receive this value?

The full source can be found [here](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/KotlinReactiveExamples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/backpressureFlowables/BackpressureOperatorThrottle.kt).

Comment: Page not found.

Comment: @andras thanks! Edited!

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood how `throttleFirst` works.

From it's javadocs:

> @param windowDuration
>
> ```
>        time to wait before emitting another item after emitting the last item
> ```

That means that `3100` should not be emitted, since `2900` was already emitted and there is only 200 milliseconds between the two and not 1 full second.

If you want to have your outputs as you have written above, you can use this:

```
.window(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.flatMap { it.take(1) }
```

instead of `throttleFirst`.

This separates the values into 1 second intervals (as observables) and takes the first value of each window.